# running a script from termux-task tasker plugin

Tags: bash, termux

I am not able to run a simple script( ls command ) from termux-tasker plugin which i am successfully able to do when i am in termux app in same directory. What could be the cause ?

Termux -tasker plugin requires  requires creation of .termux/tasker directory /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.termux/tasker  which i have done

Here are things which i have tried so far

### from termux app

```
$ sh /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.termux/tasker/script1.sh
```

$ sh ./data/data/com.termux/files/home/.termux/tasker/script1.sh

sh: 0: Can't open ./data/data/com.termux/files/home/.termux/tasker/script1.sh

$ bash /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.termux/tasker/script1.sh

$ bash ./data/data/com.termux/files/home/.termux/tasker/script1.sh

bash: ./data/data/com.termux/files/home/.termux/tasker/script1.sh: No such file or directory

$ cd /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.termux/tasker

$ ls

num.py script.sh script1.sh

$ sh script1.sh

num.py script.sh script1.sh

### from termux-tasker plugin

exec("/data/data/com.termux/files/home/.termux/tasker/script1.sh"): No such file or directory

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  https://superuser.com or other StackExchange sites. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good Luck

Comment: Also, use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as code/data/output. For more info see  and [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Did you add a proper shebang?

```
#! /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash
```

Add this line to the first line in your script. I had the same problem at first and this solved it. I think Tasker might be using `/system/bin/sh` as default.